# PayPal gateway has rejected request. %1 in Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, paypal, paypal-express, magento231

I am using Magento version 2.3.1

I have already check on magento.stackexchange.com but not getting the exact answer to solve the issue

Its setup PayPal Express Checkout method with Sandbox yes test mode

when I have placed an order from front-end so it redirecting PayPal
so pay not on that

and after that getting error on the review page
error is like that

> PayPal gateway has rejected the request. %1

not getting errors on specific error number like #10002

If anyone here helps here, thanks in advance

Comment: enable log for a paypal method and then after check PayPal log and share Paypal log info into the issue.

Comment: @DineshRajput getting response from paypal in array
  'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED' => 'false',
 'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10730',
    'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Shipping Address Postal Code Empty',
    'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'The field Shipping Address Postal Code is required',
    'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',

Comment: okay great, its clearly saying: "Shipping Address Postal Code Empty", "The field Shipping Address Postal Code is required'".  Probably you'll have to enter correct address and try to place a order.

Comment: I am sure that, Added correct address (postcode, state, country, phone no. all correct) from my site

Comment: which magento version are you using because updated Magento versions has fixed this kind of issues.

Comment: I am using Magento version 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

[image: paypal express checkout configuration]

Please check attached screenshot for paypal configuration, it is working fine in my system.

Comment: Thanks, Let me check

Comment: I have tried with this setting configuration, but giving same error :(

Comment: okay than there is something wrong with your Paypal Module. Please update latest module through composer or copy it from your local latest Magento version from "vendor/magento/module-paypal".

Comment: ok thanks, I will do that and check it again